# Unable to get Access Token from third-party server using SpringBoot-Oauth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

No matter what configuration I tried, I always get:

[image: Whitelaberl Error]

I am using the example from oauth2-vanilla: [oauth2-vanilla example](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2-vanilla)

but I alwas get the following exception when trying to login:

```
    2016-11-19 21:26:06.187 DEBUG 2753 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Created POST request for "https://api.fablabs.io/oauth/token"
2016-11-19 21:26:06.187 DEBUG 2753 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[737a5cedc764e74ddcb75bf6833516fb6fba8c20ae568fd4936e2a616fe0c30c], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:5000/login], client_id=[62c5dd374d13a7ec6469641433e20648c9cab3f10a643c5f4f55b35f11cae307], client_secret=[b98fe2e6d9214674ab25e82c5065c9aa87d61d1bd6f35f9f6ddc44aeb60f2c95]}
2016-11-19 21:26:06.639 DEBUG 2753 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "https://api.fablabs.io/oauth/token" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler
2016-11-19 21:26:06.641 DEBUG 2753 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Sat Nov 19 21:26:06 PET 2016, principal=UNKNOWN, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Could not obtain access token}]
2016-11-19 21:26:06.644 DEBUG 2753 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
```

This is my application.yml for the UI server:

```
server:
  port: 5000
  tomcat:
    remote_ip_header: x-forwarded-for
    protocol_header: x-forwarded-proto

debug: true

spring:
  aop:
    proxy-target-class: true

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: https://api.fablabs.io/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://api.fablabs.io/oauth/authorize
      clientId: 62c5dd374d13a7ec6469641433e20648c9cab3f10a643c5f4f55b35f11cae307
      clientSecret: b98fe2e6d9214674ab25e82c5065c9aa87d61d1bd6f35f9f6ddc44aeb60f2c95
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://api.fablabs.io/v0/me.json

zuul:
  routes:
    resource:
      path: /resource/**
      url: http://localhost:9000
    user:
      path: /user/**
      url: https://api.fablabs.io/v0/me.json

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

What could be wrong?? Perhaps is a problem of cookies, https, CSRF with the Auth server? I do not know how to validate this. Please provide me some help.

Apparently the [OAuth2 provider](https://github.com/fablabbcn/fablabs-api-examples) is working ok for other clients, but not working with my Java one. 
I have successfully gotten the Access Token when using Github and Google API Oauth2 endpoints. So, what could be wrong here???

Comment: I haven't seen the use of clientAuthenticationScheme in the application.yml before.  Also, presuming you have the EnableOAuth2Sso annotation used in the application?  Also, you will need the public key configured in the application.yml in order to validate the returned token.

Comment: can you describe your flow?